# One UIViewController for multiple Views

Tags: iphone

I have a UITAbleView with one section and 4 rows. i want when i click a row, a view appears, witch is a webView. i have 4 html file, when i click the first row, a view with the first html file appears, and when i click the second row, an other view appears ( witch is exactly the same, a webView, the difference is just the html file).

i have done this by creating 4 UIViewController, when i click a row, the controller1 is cerated with its view ( a webview).

is this a good to do like this ( 4 UIViewController) for a simple Views ( webView with 4 html file) or can i create juste one controller to manage all this ? if yes, what is the best prictice to do this, creating 4 UIViewController, each for one simple view or create one viewController for all the view.

thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use one view controller and load different html files in your web view according to the selected row in previous view controller.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but is the best practice with the 2 solutions.

Comment: so you have 5 view controllers? The main one and then one for each web view? Yea, you can do this with just two (or maybe even one) view controller. Think of a "controller" as something that controls a logical grouping of views. There is no reason to have a different controller when the only thing changing is the the html file. You might want to read up on MVC (model/view/controller) architecture. It works great for user interface design.